# function template taking generic vector iterators

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm trying to write a function taking a range of vector iterators, but I don't know how to write a template accepting vector iterators of any kind, like `vector<int>`, `vector<double>`, `vector<string>` etc.

This is my function so far:

```
template <typename T>
void my_print(std::vector<T>::const_iterator beg, std::vector<T>::const_iterator end)
{
    while (beg != end)
    {
        std::cout << "This is element " << *beg++ << std::endl;
    }
}
```

and the error I'm getting:

> Warning C4346:
>   'std::vector>::const_iterator': dependent name
>   is not a type CppApp  main.cpp    12 Error    IntelliSense: no instance of
>   function template "my_print" matches the argument list
>               argument types are: (std::_Vector_const_iterator>>,
>   std::_Vector_const_iterator>>)   CppApp  main.cpp    23

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You probably also want `T` to be deduced. It won't be.

Comment: @PiotrS. - I know it won't be, that's why I asked this question :)